# GPG Still sees good sign with revoked subkey still works

Tags: digital-signature, gnupg, verification, sign

I have created a key, and created a subkey. With a subkey, I signed a file. Verification works. Revoked the key, verification does not hold. This is the expected behavior.

However, If I try to sign with the same subkey and verify it still works. What am I doing wrong? Here is what am I doing in full:

```
$ gpg --gen-key
$ gpg -k
/Users/mustafa/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
---------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2019-02-03 [SC] [expires: 2021-02-02]
      5DD923FBCF6392A5CB366167D4C0627A07510C6C
uid           [ultimate] Mustafa <mustafa91@gmail.com>
sub   rsa2048 2019-02-03 [E] [expires: 2021-02-02]
```

Using edit key, add a subkey.

```
$ gpg --edit-key 5DD923FBCF6392A5CB366167D4C0627A07510C6C

sec  rsa2048/D4C0627A07510C6C
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2021-02-02  usage: SC
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa2048/E058B91696C43666
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2021-02-02  usage: E

gpg> addkey

sec  rsa2048/D4C0627A07510C6C
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2021-02-02  usage: SC
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa2048/E058B91696C43666
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2021-02-02  usage: E
ssb  rsa2048/38616BDAE66E418C
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2019-02-13  usage: S
[ultimate] (1). Mustafa <mustafa91@gmail.com>

gpg> q
Save changes? (y/N) y
```

Sign a file and verify it.

```
$ gpg --armor --detach-sign --default-key 38616BDAE66E418C  test.txt
gpg: using "38616BDAE66E418C" as default secret key for signing

$ gpg --verify test.txt.asc test.txt
gpg: Signature made Sun Feb  3 21:49:43 2019 +03
gpg:                using RSA key 485FC77FC73DA3B800C7F41538616BDAE66E418C
gpg: Good signature from "Mustafa <mustafa91@gmail.com>" [ultimate]
```

Revoke the key with message "This key is now in the hands of the enemy."

```
$ gpg --edit-key 5DD923FBCF6392A5CB366167D4C0627A07510C6C
gpg> key 2

sec  rsa2048/D4C0627A07510C6C
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2021-02-02  usage: SC
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa2048/E058B91696C43666
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2021-02-02  usage: E
ssb* rsa2048/38616BDAE66E418C
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2019-02-13  usage: S

gpg> revkey
sec  rsa2048/D4C0627A07510C6C
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2021-02-02  usage: SC
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa2048/E058B91696C43666
     created: 2019-02-03  expires: 2021-02-02  usage: E
The following key was revoked on 2019-02-03 by RSA key D4C0627A07510C6C Mustafa <mustafa91@gmail.com>
ssb  rsa2048/38616BDAE66E418C
     created: 2019-02-03  revoked: 2019-02-03  usage: S
[ultimate] (1). Mustafa <mustafa91@gmail.com>
```

Try to verify the old signature and see it fails.

```
$ gpg --verify test.txt.asc test.txt
gpg: Signature made Sun Feb  3 21:49:43 2019 +03
gpg:                using RSA key 485FC77FC73DA3B800C7F41538616BDAE66E418C
gpg: Good signature from "Mustafa <mustafa91@gmail.com>" [ultimate]
gpg: WARNING: This subkey has been revoked by its owner!
gpg: reason for revocation: Key has been compromised
gpg: revocation comment: This key is now in the hands of the enemy.
```

However, trying to sign with revoked key.

```
$ rm test.key.asc
$ gpg --armor --detach-sign --default-key 38616BDAE66E418C  test.txt
gpg: using "38616BDAE66E418C" as default secret key for signing
```

Why does it not fail? How can it be verified?

```
$ gpg --verify test.txt.asc test.txt
gpg: Signature made Sun Feb  3 21:53:11 2019 +03
gpg:                using RSA key 5DD923FBCF6392A5CB366167D4C0627A07510C6C
gpg: Good signature from "Mustafa <mustafa91@gmail.com>" [ultimate]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your last two excerpts. Despite the fact that you specified the default signing key to be `38616BDAE66E418C`, when you do the verify it reports having been signed with `D4C0627A07510C6C`.

If you utilize the `-v` verbose option of `gpg`, you will see that if the specified default key is revoked, it falls back to the next usable signing key.

To illustrate this, I recreated your scenario:

```
sec  rsa2048/4E5CB15076F1318E
     created: 2019-02-09  expires: 2021-02-08  usage: SC
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa2048/3303CBB274AECA3B
     created: 2019-02-09  expires: 2021-02-08  usage: E
The following key was revoked on 2019-02-09 by RSA key 4E5CB15076F1318E Herp Derp <herp@derp.com>
ssb  rsa2048/8ABD3900E64E7972
     created: 2019-02-09  revoked: 2019-02-09  usage: S
[ultimate] (1). Herp Derp <herp@derp.com>
```

Signing with subkey prior to revoking:

```
$ gpg -v --armor --detach-sign --default-key 8ABD3900E64E7972 test.txt
gpg: using pgp trust model
gpg: using "8ABD3900E64E7972" as default secret key for signing
gpg: using subkey 8ABD3900E64E7972 instead of primary key 4E5CB15076F1318E
gpg: writing to 'test.txt.asc'
gpg: RSA/SHA256 signature from: "8ABD3900E64E7972 Herp Derp <herp@derp.com>"
```

Signing with subkey after revoking:

```
$ gpg -v --armor --detach-sign --default-key 8ABD3900E64E7972 test.txt
gpg: Note: signature key 8ABD3900E64E7972 has been revoked
gpg: using pgp trust model
gpg: using "8ABD3900E64E7972" as default secret key for signing
gpg: Note: signature key 8ABD3900E64E7972 has been revoked
gpg: writing to 'test.txt.asc'
gpg: RSA/SHA256 signature from: "4E5CB15076F1318E Herp Derp <herp@derp.com>"
```

You can see that in the second example, gpg identifies the subkey as revoked and falls back to the primary key.

Comment: I see, I expected the GPG to fail in those scenario by default, I guess I would see it better if I exported those subkeys and worked directly with them.